# How to scroll instead of next line using the default class="menu" in foundation?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I wanted the menu to be scrollable in smaller screens (side or x-axis) instead of menu items starting a new line.

I tried setting overflow-x to auto and scroll. But the menu still starts a new line.

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 1rem; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QevmoR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of flexbox and overflow will do the trick here.
Put an overflow-x auto on the wrapper of the menu. Then you set the ul with display flex and flex-flow row nowrap. This nowrap will make sure that your menu items won't jump under each other.

```
.scroll-menu {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.scroll-menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

See my example https://jsfiddle.net/zgf7pyk6/1/